# What question has the most cycles of Close/Reopen?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, statistics, reopened-questions

Just out of curiosity, which question has been closed and reopened the most times? What caused the closing and reopening war in the first place?

Comment: For your information: answer can't be closed or reopened, only question. Edited to fix the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here's a data explorer query that should answer your question.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/453492/community-controversy)

It returns the following 3 posts:
[Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113)
[What is the worst programming language you ever worked with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961942)
[How to pair socks from a pile efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881)

These were pretty obviously closed/reopened so many times, because they're ["fun"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) questions. Not terrifically useful, but they're good reads when you're killing time.

---

Correction...

The above query queries Stack Overflow, you'll have to switch sites to check other communities, but from what little digging I did, few other sites have posts that went through more than 5 cycles.

Answer (score 3):

The per site query was nicely offered  by [apaul34208](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277176/158100) so I decided to make the  [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/688200) that offers the networkwide result in one go:

```sql
-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results ( site nvarchar(250)
                      , postid int
                      , title nvarchar(250)
                      , cls int
                      , opn int);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , id
     , title
     , [closed]
     , [re-opened]
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts p
inner join (
select top 10 postid
     , [10] as [closed]
     , [11] as [re-opened]
     from ( select postid, posthistorytypeid 
            from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posthistory
            where posthistorytypeid in (10,11) --close/reopen
           ) as src
pivot ( 
  count(posthistorytypeid)
  for posthistorytypeid
  in ([10], [11])
) as pvt
order by [10]+[11] desc
) ph on ph.postid = p.id
-- order  by [closed]+ [re-opened] desc
' 
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

print @sql

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

-- show results

select  site , 
       -- URL builder from Lamak http://stackoverflow.com/a/38129701
       'http://' 
      + case PARSENAME(site,1)
        when 'audio' then 'avp'
        else PARSENAME(site,1)
        end 
      + coalesce('.' 
        + case PARSENAME(site,2)
          when 'audio' then 'avp'
          else PARSENAME(site,2)
          end , '')
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , ''
      , coalesce('.' + PARSENAME(site,3), '')
      )
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , '.net'
      , '.com'
      ) 
      + '/q/'
      + cast(postid as nvarchar)
      + '|'
      + title 
      -- rest of columns
      site
      , [cls]
      , [opn]
from #results
order by [cls] + [opn] desc

drop table #results
```

I used the [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) query functionality of SQL Server to get the top 10 per site. You can can find the initial revisions of that query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/688198) which was used for debug purposes.

I also included all meta sites so you can follow along on the biggest drama's.

Here is the result when run today (remember that SEDE only refreshes once a week on Sunday).
[image]

Comment: Ha, I knew that "Time to take a stand" will be the top one :D. Too bad that "open" is equal to "close".

Comment: @Tom you don't get more "closed" than "locked" though :)